Get the IP address/es for scheduled and automate flows to add them to the white list inside external API
We have an automate flow and a scheduled flow which integrate with external API using the Premium connector "Send Http request". now we want to secure the calls to the external API endpoints, by building a whitelist inside the external system, for the IPs that can call the external API. so how we can get the IP addresses for the automate and scheduled flows which calls the external API, so we can add them to the whitelist?
Also, the Power automate flows are inside solutions inside Dev & PROD environments that has United states as their region, as follow: -

Thanks

The outbound IP addresses for Power Platform are probably what you’re looking for. As of this writing, those for the United States region are:
52.188.157.160, 40.77.68.110, 40.65.220.25, 52.181.180.194, 52.181.182.180, 52.151.217.109, 52.151.217.66


ok thanks yes i think this list should work, but will/might this list change in the future? if the answer is yes, then is there a way to know in advance when those IPs will change so we can modify the whitelist accordingly ?

@microsoftdeveloperdesigner The linked page references the associated Discovery API, which you could write a script to pull these IPs from on a regular basis, should you so desire.
